# Design considerations when implementing/distributing updates for application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, updates

I have already designed an applications that is nothing more than a simple WinForm with one or two classes to handle data and collection.

Fairly often I find myself refactoring parts of it or adding new features to it, not huge features but small additions to its functionality.

The question I have is what would be the best way to provide an updated program to the user after they have initially downloaded it.

I have thought of a few different options already:

1. Upload a new version with improvements on CodePlex
2. Host the application on my personal website but change the file with the latest version
3. Implement some sort of system that will work in a way similar to add-ons to add the     functionality.

Is there a way to provide an updated application without the user having to essentially replace their current version by deleting it and replacing it with a newly downloaded one? Although the CodePlex idea seems worthwhile I wasn't sure if there was a better or easier way.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) was designed for.

I've used it regularly in a corporate setting,but it would also be appropriate for an Internet deployment scenario.  You may want to invest in a certificate so you can sign your code if this is a commercial product.

**Added**
Here's a shorter article with a lot of screen shots.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm

(Still looking for more good links).

**Added - final addition**

Wikipedia sums it up succinctly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce

Comment: It's not a commercial product, just a simple tool.
Does ClickOnce rely on the application being stored on a server? I only briefly read the MSDN article.

Comment: The file can (and usually does) sit on a server. However, you can put it on a CD, or on a Network Share. There are a lot of articles in the link I posted, but in reality, it is SUPER easy to use. I'll try to find a better link. I know I've seen it explained in one page, including instructions.